# Extensions directory error in 3.4.6

Tags: extension

After I enter my extensions directory and save, this message appears: "Public directory down or too slow - please contact CiviCRM team on forums." Appears the extensions directory on civicrm.org may have moved since 3.4 was released?

Answer (score 2):

That's entirely possible - CiviCRM 3.4 is about seven years old, and end-of-life support for it would have been about six years ago tops.  An upgrade is strongly recommended; such an old version would be extremely insecure at this point.

Comment: Yes, I know it's an old version. Meanwhile, the question about where extensions are hosted on civicrm.org remains unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The default extension directory is located at:

`https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver={ver}|cms={uf}`

For instance:
https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=3.4|cms=drupal